# How to stop fake members from signing up? These are not bots

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

I have an old dating site and I'm having some real problems lately with fake members signing up. The problem is these are NOT bots, they are real people (but scammers) browsing throughout the site, signing up and trying to contact our real members, which is a real pain.

Here is what I have implemented:

- reCaptcha
- IP logging - Banning IPs
- Email Verification
- User is required to fill out entire profile

I can see based from IP addresses that many of these fake members are usually from various countries in Africa (Nigeria, Ghana, etc), but they will state in their profiles that they are from America. Or there will be a US profile that says they are from Arizona, but their IP will show New York. These members are easy to find and block. (Yet after all the work they have to do to get a profile set up on my site and have it banned, they keep coming back)

**PROBLEM:**
Some members are really experienced scammers and their IP addresses match their user profile US-based location exactly. In some cases, I know they are fake members, but in other cases I'm not so sure. The only other tool I have is to manually search for their profile descriptions line-by-line on Google to find their profiles on other sites, to see if there is anything suspicious.

Sometimes this works, but sometimes their profiles are the same on other sites and nothing seems "off", and sometimes their profiles are completely unique to my site and cannot be found anywhere else. Yet their profile and photo seems "off" (super model photo?), they'll still attempt to contact other members immediately...

Any advice on what to do about combating these type of advanced fake members? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Simply you can't, except if you want to ask for their ID and check it manually (still they can fake that) + I don't think a dating website users will tolerate you asking for such thing.

Comment: If you saved their profiles before deleting them you may see some patterns in their descriptions. If they message too fast after subscribing, or fill their profile too fast you may raise a flag. You can run a reverse image search on the pics and raise a flag if it returns something other than a social media pic with matching first name.

Comment: The Google search you do manually could be done programatically

Answer (score 0):

It is common for their IP location to not match their address. These people maybe behind VPNs. This means they are somewhat savvy and do spend money.

You can try requiring a phone number. This helps contacting them and gage trust.

How I see the problem, your time is better spent servicing these new members. Incorporate features like a helpdesk and use a customer centric strategy. Bad behavior can be discourage with expiring bans and holding back site features.